# Changing Date Based From Value in Dropdown in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I have this payment term that is a dropdown. And that payment term has values. So i need to add those value from the current date so i can display it. Here's my code below.

```
this.addForm = this.fb.group({
      payment_term: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      due_date: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
});



onSelectPaymentTerm(event){
    console.log(event)
    this.addForm.patchValue({
      due_date: this.date.setDate( this.date.getDate() + event)
    })
  }
```

> HTML

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Payment Term</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="payment_term" (ngModelChange)="onSelectPaymentTerm($event)">
            <option value="null" hidden>-- Select Payment Term --</option>
            <option *ngFor="let payment of payments" [value]="payment?.value">{{ payment?.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Due Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="due_date" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @AbhijitKar. I can't set the date based to the payment term values dropdown? Somethings wrong with my code i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have a look at the following - using Vanilla JS

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/changing-date-based-from-value-in-dropdown-in-angular-4)

> Cleaner Approach - using moment.js

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/changing-date-based-from-value-in-dropdown-moment-js)

> Solution

1. Use Reactive form through and through
2. No need to use `(ngModelChange)="onSelectPaymentTerm($event)"`. But this wasn't the problem
3. Selected value comes as a string, and hence must be converted to integer with parseInt before adding to the date
4. Prefer Moment.js for date manipulation in Javascript

Comment: I forked your link. I mean if the value is 90, then it would add 90 days from now and if 50 is chosen, it would add 50 days from now. Here's the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/changing-date-based-from-value-in-dropdown-in-angular-4-wxxwym?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Joseph I have updated the StackBlitz Demo to your specifications!

Comment: Thank you. Can you edit the date to just this for example. "Sat Apr 21 2018"

Comment: @Joseph, sure, I have made the change to the Demo, Have a look!

Comment: Is this the link right? https://stackblitz.com/edit/changing-date-based-from-value-in-dropdown-in-angular-4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts. I can still see the time and the GMT +...

Comment: @Joseph do you want cleaner output?

Comment: Yes Please :) Just the date. Thanks a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166079/discussion-between-abhijit-kar-and-joseph).

Comment: @Joseph Done, have a look at the changes!

Comment: @Joseph just wait for a while, I am adding a cleaner approach, by using Moment.js (It eases interactions with Dates)

Comment: Ok. :)))))))))))

Comment: Thank you for that. One last thing. How can i get the id of payment term when i submit it? I have forked the link here https://stackblitz.com/edit/changing-date-based-from-value-in-dropdown-moment-js-ukntbg?file=app/app.component.ts. Thank you.

Comment: @Joseph I have updated the 2nd demo, Moment.js version, with id of payment.

Comment: @Joseph sure, I don't see why not!